# Install macos 10.13 Guest OS on VMware ESXi 6.0 fails

Tags: vmware-esxi, mac-osx

I want to install macos 10.13, High Sierra, on VMware ESXi, 6.0.0, 5572656.

According to VMware's compatibility guide this should be supported. https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=Software&productid=44496&vcl=true&supRel=338,273,398,274,275,276,367,369,408,437,427&testConfig=16

However, macos 10.13 is not a choice when creating a new VM.
[image]

Is there another way to install it or is it not supported on this patch level of ESXi?

Comment: What happened when you selected 10.10 and installed it anyway?

Comment: It fails to boot.  It does not boot from the hard drive and defaults to the blue screen "Boot Manager" prompt.

Comment: I found this post on a VMware forum that says macos 10.13 works on ESXi 6.5 Update 2, https://communities.vmware.com/thread/590168.  But I'd like to know where that documentation is.